# ASP.net error: Mismatch between code file and inherit attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

Opening a page in Enterprise Portal results in an error shown in Windows-Event-Log:

MyControl.ascx.cs(15): error ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Line 15 is marked with (X) in the source below.

**ASCX.CS file:**

```
namespace Company.Productgroup
{
    (X) public partial class Productname : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**ASCX file:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Productname.ascx.cs" Inherits="Company.Productgroup.Productname" %>
```

**ASCX.designer.cs file:**

```
namespace Company.Productgroup    {
    public partial class Productname : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**What I tried:**

- Changing the atribute `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile` and vice versa
- Removing Namespace from ASCX.cs Removing Namespace from
- ASCX.designer.cs Changing Inherits attribute in ASCX file to
- Productname / Productgroup.Productname
- Searched Google / SO for a solution. In nearly every result, the
  problem was a non-match between Inherit-attribute and
  namepace/classname, eg: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776781/asp-net-error-about-inherits-attribute-even-though-its-correct), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517124/make-sure-that-the-class-defined-in-this-code-file-matches-the-inherits-attrib), [Link3](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/413381/Make-sure-that-the-class-defined-in-this-code-file)

**What is fact:**

- All files are stored in the same directory, so no paths-problems
  should occur.
- Default namespace in VS project is set to `Company.Productgroup`

Answer (score 0):

Your `designer` file seems to be the problem. In it the class name is `Product` while in the other two files it is `Productname`. It's a little odd that it would be out of sync because the designer file is generated but I have seen it happen. Try fixing it manually and see what happens.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments I decided to take a look at some of our ASCXs to see what might be different. In none of ours did the `designer` file show the inheritance chain. For example:

**AutoHideField.ascx.cs**

```
namespace Foo
{
    public partial class AutoHideField : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

**AutoHideField.ascx.designer.cs**

```
namespace Foo
{
    public partial class AutoHideField
```

**AutoHideField.ascx**

```
<%@ Control ... Inherits="Foo.AutoHideField" %>
```

Comment: +1 The classes must have the same name. They're actually both part of the same class (or should be, when named properly) because it's a partial class.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Classname was out of sync. But anyway - after changing it (I've adjusted code in the original post also), I'm getting the same failure.

Comment: I updated the answer based on further research (looking at some of our  ASCXs).